# Xhttp is not firing request in firefox add on

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to make an add on which records the URLs I visits. the data is supposed to be posted to my site.

I have manifest.json

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "add_link",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "button to post current page url to my site",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/", "*://www.youtube.com/*", "http://127.0.0.1:3000/links", "http://127.0.0.1:3000/*"],
      "js": ["add_link.js", "jquery.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

and add_link.js

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "http://xlinks.herokuapp.com/links", true);
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('link[url]', window.location.href)
xhttp.send(fd);
```

Any clue about why it's not working?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have permission to the remote server(s) to send cross-origin requests

In your case, you should add something like this to your manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "add_link",
    ...
    "permissions": [
        "http://xlinks.herokuapp.com/links"
        "activeTab",
        "tabs"
    ]
    ...
}
```

More information:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission